# Without invoking Riesz's representation theorem, why do Hodge duals exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Working through Peter Szekeres's *Course in Modern Mathematical Physics* and I'm running into some confusion in its development of the Hodge dual. In particular, I'm not clear on what justification the book is using for its existence.

Choose a basis and let $E$ be its volume element. Let $A\in\Lambda^p(V)$ let the map $f_A:\Lambda^{n-p}(V)\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $A\land B=f_A(B)E$. It's easy to check that $f_A$ is a linear functional. Szekeres claims on page 223:

> ...as the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $\Lambda^{n-p}(V)$ is non-singular there exists a unique $(n-p)$-vector $\ast A$ such that $f_A(B)=(\ast A,B)$...

Ignoring the "non-singular" part, this claim is clearly immediately true by the Riesz representation theorem. However, this bit of algebra/analysis isn't introduced in the text until way later. What I'm interested in is what justification is being used *here*.

What the book defines as being non-singular is the following property of inner products on page 127:

> If $u\cdot v=0$ for all $v\in V$ then $u=0$.

Am I missing something obvious? I don't see the chain of reasoning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the finite-dimensional case, the Riesz theorem is pretty much trivial for non-degenerate bilinear forms, because it follows almost immediately from definition.

Let $W$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ (in your case, it's the $p^{th}$ exterior power), and $g$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form on $W$, i.e $g:W \times W \to \Bbb{R}$ is bilinear, and
\begin{align}
\text{for all $x\in W$, if  for all $y \in W$, $g(x,y) = 0$ then $x=0$.}
\end{align}
Note that another way to state the definition of non-degeneracy is as follows. We shall define a linear map $g^{\flat}:W \to W^*$ by the rule:
\begin{align}
g^{\flat}(x) &:= g(x, \cdot) \in W^*
\end{align}
In other words, for any $x \in W$,  $g^{\flat}(x) \in W^*$ is that element such that for all $y\in W$, we have
\begin{align}
(g^{\flat}(x))(y):= g(x,y).
\end{align}
Then, the statement of non-degeneracy is that
\begin{align}
g^{\flat}(x) = 0 \implies x = 0.
\end{align}
It's a basic linear algebra theorem that this is equivalent to saying $g^{\flat}:W \to W^*$ is injective. Now, since $W$ is finite-dimensional, $W^*$ has the same dimension, so $g^{\flat}$ is actually an isomorphism. The inverse map is typically denoted $g^{\sharp} := (g^{\flat})^{-1}:W^* \to W$.

Now, note that for all $f\in W^*$, and all $x \in W$, we have
\begin{align}
f(x) &= [(g^{\flat} \circ g^{\sharp})(f)](x) \tag{since $g^{\flat} \circ g^{\sharp} = \text{id}_{W^*}$} \\
&= [g^{\flat}(g^{\sharp}(f))](x) \\
&:= g\left( g^{\sharp}(f), x \right) \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}
\end{align}

---

In your case, $f_A \in W^* = \left( \Lambda^{n-p}(V)\right)^*$. Since $(\cdot, \cdot) =g$ is non-degenerate, it provides us with an isomorphism $g^{\sharp}:\left( \Lambda^{n-p}(V)\right)^* \to \Lambda^{n-p}(V)$. Hence, the "vector" associated with the "covector" $f_A$ is
\begin{align}
\star A &:= g^{\sharp}(f_A) \equiv \bigg((\cdot, \cdot) \bigg)^{\sharp}(f_A) \in \Lambda^{n-p}(V).
\end{align}

Hence, non-degeneracy of $(\cdot, \cdot)$ implies the existence of a unique $\star A \in W = \Lambda^{n-p}(V)$, and if you compare with formula $(\ddot{\smile})$, you'll see that for all $B$, we have
\begin{align}
f_A(B) &= (\star A, B).
\end{align}

---

By the way, the maps $g^{\flat}$ (read as "$g$-flat") and $g^{\sharp}$ (read as "$g$-sharp") are called the musical isomorphisms.